# The exit status code for the 'grep' command

Tags: grep

The *[grep](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)* manual at the exit status section report:

```
EXIT STATUS
       The  exit  status is 0 if selected lines are found, and 1 if not
       found.  If an error occurred the exit status is 2.  (Note: POSIX
       error handling code should check for '2' or greater.)
```

But the command:

```
echo ".
..
test.zip"|grep -vE '^[.]'
echo $?

echo "test.zip
test.txt"|grep -vE '^[.]'
echo $?
```

The value returned is always 0. I would have expected 1 and 0. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: exit status is `1` if grep doesn't find any match.. both your given samples returns at least one matching line.. so exit status is `0` for both cases..

Comment: You question could be replaced with: "Why does `grep -vE '^[.]' <<<$'.\na'; echo $?` output 0?"

Comment: @Sundeep no '^[.]' match only what starts with a point, perhaps it is not clear that the input is multiline?

Comment: @MichaWiedenmann  yes but the problem is not that.

Comment: @bandabassotti May I kindly suggest, that you are a little confused, sundeep explained that exactly because the line is multiline and there is a line which matches your pattern, you get your result. (Grep is line base.)

Comment: `-v` selects the lines that are not matching the pattern. Both command lines you posted contain lines that are not matching the `^[.]` pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Remember that `grep` is line based. If any line matches, you got a match. (In your first case `test.zip` matches (more precisely: you used `-v` therefore you have asked for lines that do not match your pattern, and `test.zip` does exactly that, i.e. does not match your pattern. As a result your grep call was successful). Compare

```
$ grep -vE '^[.]' <<<$'.\na'; echo $?
a
0
```

with

```
$ grep -vE '^[.]' <<<$'.\n.'; echo $?
1
```

Note how the first command outputs the line `a`, that is it has found a match, which is why the exit status is 0. Compare that with the second example, where no line was matched.

**References**

`<<<` is a here string:

```
Here Strings
    A variant of here documents, the format is:

           [n]<<<word

    The word undergoes brace  expansion,  tilde  expansion,  parameter  and
    variable  expansion,  command  substitution,  arithmetic expansion, and
    quote removal.  Pathname expansion and  word  splitting  are  not  per-
    formed.   The  result  is  supplied  as a single string, with a newline
    appended, to the command on its standard input (or file descriptor n if
    n is specified).
```

```
   $ cat <<<'hello world'
   hello world
```

`$'1\na'` is used to get a multi line input (`\n` is replaced by newline within `$'string'`, for more see `man bash`).

```
$ echo $'1\na'
1
a
```